# Variables from mysql to javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

Theres a database on mysql, it consists field with a link to the image.
How can i draw this image(s) with javascript/jquery? Whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "draw image"? Usually you would just put the link to the image into a src attribute of a html img tag. Of course you can put it there by javascript.

Comment: thanks, it really looks like duplication. flagged it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some serverside scripting (like PHP) to retrieve the information (the link) from your MySQL database. Afterwards your PHP script can render the link in your HTML (or JavaScript if you like).